# NUMA support on which CPU? What are the current server configuration of this kind of CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu, numa

NUMA support on which CPU? What are the current server configuration of this kind of CPU? Linux NUMA commands regarding what, how to open NUMA?

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend of your server, if it's using a multicore cpu that support Numa affinity. Type `numactl --hardware` and you'll check how it's the current configuration, for example:

> available: 2 nodes (0-1)
>   node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>   node 0 size: 32733 MB
>   node 0 free: 4027 MB
>   node 1 cpus: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
>   node 1 size: 32767 MB
>   node 1 free: 20898 MB
>   node distances:
>   node   0   1 
>     0:  10  21 
>     1:  21  10

If you want to check performance with your application, just make sure that it's using the CPUs from the same numa node. You can check this using `ps -aux` or`top` commands.